# Airflow macro not being read as expected

Tags: python, airflow

I need an Airflow macro value, but the string returned is not being read as expected, all I get is a broken DAG. I've tested part of the script in terminal to see if there was something wrong, but it doesn't seem to be the case.

My expectation is that a string like '2016-06-28T16:51:45.978473-05:00' turns into '2016-06-28T16:51'

Here is the code. This part comes before the DAG decorator scope `with DAG(..) as dag:`.

```py
exec_date = '{{ execution_date }}'
exec_date = re.findall(r"^[\d]{4}-[\d]{2}-[\d]{2}T[\d]{2}:[\d]{2}", exec_date)[0]
```

The error message:

```
Broken DAG: [<path-to-dag>/processing_dag.py] Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<path-to-dag>/processing_dag.py", line 16, in <module>
    exec_date = re.findall(r"^[\d]{4}-[\d]{2}-[\d]{2}T[\d]{2}:[\d]{2}", exec_date)[0]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Which means that I'm not getting `'{{ execution_date }}'` in the format specified by [Airflow docs](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/macros-ref.html).

Running the DAG script out of the Airflow server won't activate macros and the DAG is broken, so I don't know how to debug the code. Is there a way to print the value of `'{{ execution_date }}'` so I can understand what is happening?

[EDIT] As requested, here are some relevant parts of the script. Imported modules are:

```py
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.dummy import DummyOperator
from datamechanics_airflow_plugin.operator import DataMechanicsOperator
from airflow.models import Variable
from airflow.utils.dates import days_ago
from datetime import datetime
import pendulum
import re
```

Top of the script:

```py
local_tz = pendulum.timezone("America/Sao_Paulo")
exec_date = '{{ execution_date }}'
exec_date = re.findall(r"^[\d]{4}-[\d]{2}-[\d]{2}T[\d]{2}:[\d]{2}", exec_date)[0]
exec_date = datetime.strptime(exec_date, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M")


with DAG(
    dag_id="processing_dag",
    start_date=days_ago(0, second = 1).astimezone(tz=local_tz),
    schedule_interval="@daily",
) as dag:

  <tasks, etc>...
```

Comment: share the relevant parts of your dag

Comment: I've edited the question to show more details

Comment: where are you using exec_date?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jinja templated strings or macros are not evaluated until task/DAG runtime.  However, top-level code (aka logic that is present outside of an operator's `execute()` method) is executed every file-parsing interval of the Scheduler.

What's happening here is these two lines of code are evaluating the *literal string* of `{{ execution_date }}` rather than a datetime string as you are expecting:

```py
exec_date = re.findall(r"^[\d]{4}-[\d]{2}-[\d]{2}T[\d]{2}:[\d]{2}", exec_date)[0]
exec_date = datetime.strptime(exec_date, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M")
```

The error that's being thrown is by the Scheduler parsing the DAG file and executing the top-level code.  Since the regex expression doesn't return a result, the index access fails because there is no matching regex string pattern in the literal string `{{ execution_date }}`.

Ideally, the Jinja expression and associated logic would be part of a `template_field`, noted in the operator documentation, or within the logic of the operator being called.